# Spring JTA Transaction fail to roll back

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, transactions, jta

I need help to figure why my JTA transaction failed to really roll back despite seeing a rollback message in the log. 
My setup has a MySQL database and a Microsoft SQLserver database.  I created 2 JNDI  (tomcat-7) resources for transactional DataSource to both databases ( see my META-INF/context.xml ).

I called com.my.AService.create(obj) . It is a method which will raise an exception to test whether rollback works. At the end of test , I can see in the log that there is a rollback message. But When I check the databases , I see committed records that should have been rollback. (see my truncated log )

Why did the rollback not working ?  How do I fix it ?

I am using :
Apache Tomcat 7.0.50
jtom
Spring framework 3.2.3 RELEASE

Trucated Log where I see a rollback message for the Null pointer exception:

```
2014-03-06 11:42:06,103 DEBUG [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute] - <Applying rules to determine whether transaction should rollback on java.lang.NullPointerException>
2014-03-06 11:42:06,103 DEBUG [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute] - <Winning rollback rule is: RollbackRuleAttribute with pattern [Exception]>
...
2014-03-06 11:42:06,104 DEBUG [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager] - <Initiating transaction rollback>
2014-03-06 11:42:06,105 DEBUG [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager] - <Triggering afterCompletion synchronization>
2014-03-06 11:42:06,105 DEBUG [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager] - <Clearing transaction synchronization>
```

Snippets form my projects:

webapp/META-INF/context.xml :

```
<Context>
    <Resource
        name="TransactionSynchronizationRegistry"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.transaction.TransactionSynchronizationRegistry"
        factory="org.objectweb.jotm.TransactionSynchronizationRegistryFactory"/>

    <Transaction
        factory="org.objectweb.jotm.UserTransactionFactory"
        jotm.timeout="60"/>

    <!-- -->
    <!--  DO I NEED defaultAutoCommit="false"  in the following Reources ???? --> 
    <!-- -->
    <Resource driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
              factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" 
              name="jdbc/mysqldb" 
              password="secret" 
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
              url="jdbc:mysql://mysqlserver:3306/mysqldb1"
              username="myuser"/>
    <ResourceLink global="jdbc/mysqldb" name="jdbc/mysqldb" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

    <Resource driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 
              factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" 
              name="jdbc/mssqldb" 
              password="secret" 
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
              url="jdbc:sqlserver://sqlserver;portNumber=1433;databaseName=mssqldb1;" 
              username="myuser" />
    <ResourceLink global="jdbc/mssqldb" name="jdbc/mssqldb" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</Context>
```

inside my WEB-INF/web.xml :

```
<resource-env-ref>
    <description>forum db connection</description>
    <resource-env-ref-name>jdbc/mysqldb</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>javax.sql.DataSource</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>

<resource-env-ref>
    <description>xdg db connection</description>
    <resource-env-ref-name>jdbc/mssqldb</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>javax.sql.DataSource</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>

<resource-env-ref>
    <description>JTA transaction manager</description>
    <resource-env-ref-name>jta/UserTransaction</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>javax.transaction.UserTransaction</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>

<resource-env-ref>
    <description>JTA transaction synchronization registry</description>
    <resource-env-ref-name>TransactionSynchronizationRegistry</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>javax.transaction.TransactionSynchronizationRegistry</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
```

I copied the following into /tomcat7.0.50/lib  :

```
carol-iiop-delegate.jar
carol-interceptors.jar
carol.jar
carol.properties
commons-logging-api.jar
jotm-core.jar
jotm-datasource.jar
log4j.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar
ow2-connector-1.5-spec.jar
ow2-jta-1.1-spec.jar
sqljdbc4.jar
xapool.jar
```

Spring config inside my WEB-INF/config/root-context.xml  :

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="mysqlDataSourceTx" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/mysqldb" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSourceTx" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/mssqldb" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionSynchronizationRegistryName" value="java:comp/env/TransactionSynchronizationRegistry"/>
    <property name="transactionManagerName" value="java:comp/UserTransaction"/>
</bean>

<bean id="adDao" class="com.my.dao.ADDaoJdbcImpl">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSourceTx"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="amDao" class="com.my.dao.AMDaoJdbcImpl">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSourceTx"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="aDao" class="com.my.dao.AJdbcImpl">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSourceTx"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="fService" class="com.my.service.FService">
    <property name="dataSource"> 
        <ref bean="mysqlDataSourceTx"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="bDao" class="com.my.dao.BDaoJdbcImpl">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSourceTx"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="read*" read-only="true"/>
        <tx:method name="create*" propagation="REQUIRED" rollback-for="Exception"/>
        <tx:method name="update*" propagation="REQUIRED" rollback-for="Exception"/>
        <tx:method name="delete*" propagation="REQUIRED" rollback-for="Exception"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<tx:advice id="txDaoAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="read*" read-only="true"/>
        <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true"/>
        <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" rollback-for="Exception"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<tx:advice id="txGeneralAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" rollback-for="Exception"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>


<!-- use proxy-target-class to force use of CGLIB -->
<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
    <aop:pointcut id="aServiceOperation" expression="execution(* com.my.service.AService.*(..))" />
    <aop:pointcut id="daoOperation3" expression="execution(* com.my.dao.AJdbcImpl.*(..))" />
    <aop:pointcut id="daoOperation4" expression="execution(* com.my.dao.BDaoJdbcImpl.*(..))" />
    <aop:pointcut id="fServiceOperation" expression="execution(* com.my.service.FService.*(..))" />

    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="aServiceOperation"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txDaoAdvice" pointcut-ref="daoOperation3"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txDaoAdvice" pointcut-ref="daoOperation4"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txGeneralAdvice" pointcut-ref="fServiceOperation"/>
</aop:config>

<!--  NO  tx:annotation-driven  -->
<bean id="aService" class="com.my.service.AService">
</bean>
```

Partial Code for com.my.service.AService  :

```
package com.my.service;

// omitted import statements

public class AService implements IAService {
    @Autowired AJdbcImpl aDao;
    @Autowired BDaoJdbcImpl bDao;
    @Autowired FService fService;

    public AService() {
        // empty
    }

    @Override
    public List<ARecord> readAll() {
        return aDao.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Asset create(ARecord obj) {
        String name = bDao.getNameFromId(obj.getBRecordId());

        // create my_sql record
        int new_mysql_id = fService.createTRecord(name);

        obj.setTRecordId(new_mysql_id);

        // create MS Sqlserver record
        int new_sqlserver_id = aDao.create(obj);
        obj.setId(new_sqlserver_id);

        // raise an exception to test rollback
        String nullString = null;
        int BLOW_UP_HERE_WITH_NULL_POINTER_REFERENCING  = nullString.length();

        return obj;
    }

    //
    // omitted update() , and delete() code 
    //
}
```

Partial Code for com.my.service.IAService  :

```
package com.my.service;

// omitted import statements

public interface IAService {
  List<ARecord> readAll();
  Asset create(ARecord obj);
  //
  // omitted update() , and delete()
}
```

Comment: Posting more complete logs, especially from `org.springframework.transaction` might help. What records are in the base exactly?

Comment: I ended up using atomikos instead of jotm in my final solution. JOTM seems to have no update for many years.